# How to change "comment line action" behaviour for particular language in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

For Javascript, comment line action inserts "{/* */}" around line. I prefer simple "//"

I haven't seen changing comment body option in standard settings nor in the specific language settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you're using the correct command/shortcut?

If you open the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette) and type in "toggle line comment", that's the command you're looking for, as opposed to the "toggle block comment" command.

You can also open your [keyboard shortcuts](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_keyboard-shortcuts-editor) and search for "toggle line comment" to verify the shortcut is what you expect it to be.

Comment: Actually you are right. It does work. I've been trying to comment out html-like snippet in JS file. Example: <p> foo </p>  =>  {/*<p> foo </p>*/}